# Istio (envoy) rate limits for matching the absence of a header

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

We'd like to implement `envoyFilters` that allow us to apply a local rate limit of 20 requests as maximum per minute to all traffic that has not a particular header. Idea is to limit the amount of request to all non-authenticated users which should lack the header `x-user-auth: some_value`.

All requests are done to the same Kubernetes service and from different/undetermined origins. We are not using any Istio `ingressgateway`, but all the pods that are part of the circuit of these requests have the Istio sidecar proxy injected into them.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using the local rate limit, but external service that acts as our ratelimiter - I've described it in more details in this article:  https://domagalski-j.medium.com/istio-rate-limits-for-egress-traffic-8697df490f68

So in my case it was just a matter of adjusting [envoy actions](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-ratelimit-action). I've changed it from generic_key to request_headers - as you can read in the [docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-config-route-v3-ratelimit-action-requestheaders), request_headers have an option: skip_if_absent  - if left blank then if a given header is not attached to the request, the request is not forwarded to rate limiter service.
You are trying to ratelimit everything that doesn't have a particular header so maybe ["header_value_match"](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-config-route-v3-ratelimit-action-headervaluematch) action will suits you better, as it has "expect_match" field that you may use.

This is EnvoyFilter I've used in istio:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: route-httpbin
  namespace: default
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: bastion-box
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: "httpbin.org:80"
            route:
              name: "default"
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          route:
            rate_limits:
              - actions:
                  - request_headers:
                      header_name: "X-Client-Id"
                      descriptor_key: "clientId"
                  - request_headers:
                      header_name: "X-Credential-Username"
                      descriptor_key: "username"
```

I also found this article very helpful to understand envoy filters:
https://www.aboutwayfair.com/tech-innovation/understanding-envoy-rate-limits

Answer (score 1):

Looking over Envoy's Rate Limit Service [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/service/ratelimit/v3/rls.proto), there is no obvious way to limit request rates based on headers.

However, such configuration may be possible with Istio's [Request Routing](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/) and [Rate Limits](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/).
Creating [route based on user identity](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/#route-based-on-user-identity) matching headers

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
...
spec:
  hosts:
  - foo
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        x-user-auth:
          exact: <some_value>
    route:
    - destination:
        host: foo
        subset: bar
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: foo
        subset: baz
```

and creating services with [local rate limiting](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#local-rate-limit).

This configuration wil, hopefully, redirect requests with `x-user-auth` header to non-limited service (bar), and everyone else to a limited one (baz).

Comment: This is an approach we are trying to avoid in favor of let's say "pure" ratelimits. It will certainly be our go-to if we can't make it tough. We are trying to follow this documentation https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/local_rate_limit_filter#using-rate-limit-descriptors-for-local-rate-limiting while using the "header_value_match" described here: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-ratelimit-action-headervaluematch
What do you think? would that be doable?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it would first add the header `x-test-rate-limit` (as per example) to requests without `x-user-auth`, and then limit rates based on `x-test-rate-limit`. It's the other way around then what I suggested, but it should work. However I'm not knowledgable enough to give you an example configuration.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand it but I thought that `x-test-rate-limit` was added when ratelimit was applied while using `expect_match` to false would apply the limit to anything not matching a certain header key/value. Seems that I have a lot more reading to do :(